# Android Wifi Hardware Module

Tags: android, linux

Is it possible to get my device's wifi hardware info using adb. 
I am looking for info like manufacturer, module info etc..

Here is what i tried.

```
adb shell
lspci
lspci | less
lspci | grep -i intel
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

And this

```
adb shell
```

Output

```
shell@android:/ $ lspci
lspci: applet not found
1|shell@android:/ $ modinfo iwlagn
/system/bin/sh: modinfo: not found
127|shell@android:/ $ 

modinfo iwlagn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try uploading a modified busybox containing that module (lspci)

Comment: Where i can find info to do this?